# Reducing an array of Row Tuples to their unique values with PySpark

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

Setup the dataframe :

```
data = [
 (Row(id='label1'), Row(id='label1')),
 (Row(id='label1'), Row(id='label6')),
 (Row(id='label6'), Row(id='label1')),
 (Row(id='label6'), Row(id='label6'))]

df = sc.parallelize(data)

df.collect()
```

returns :

```
[(Row(id='label1'), Row(id='label1')),
 (Row(id='label1'), Row(id='label6')),
 (Row(id='label6'), Row(id='label1')),
 (Row(id='label6'), Row(id='label6'))]
```

This dataset is reduced, the actual dataset contains many more labels. I'm attempting to remove duplicates. To remove duplicates from :

```
[(Row(id='label1'), Row(id='label1')),
 (Row(id='label1'), Row(id='label6')),
 (Row(id='label6'), Row(id='label1')),
 (Row(id='label6'), Row(id='label6'))]
```

The following should be returned :

```
[(Row(id='label1'), Row(id='label6'))]
```

So Rows that contain same labels are removed or same labels in other Tuple position are removed.

Closest I've got got is :

```
df.map(lambda k : k[0]).toDF().distinct().collect()
```

which returns :

```
[Row(id='label6'), Row(id='label1')]
```

But this an array of rows instead of an array of Row Tuples : `[(Row(id='label6'), Row(id='label1'))]`

Update :

Each Row also contain a SparseVector that I've omitted in attempt to focus on issue. A comparison function is executed against each Row's `SparseVector` Rows `label1,label1` and `label6,label6` are not compared as these contain same labels. Either `label1,label6` or `label6,label1` are not cmpared as comparing label1,label6 and label6,label1 will return same value.

Update 2:

```
data = [
 (Row(id='label1'), Row(id='label1')),
 (Row(id='label1'), Row(id='label6')),
 (Row(id='label6'), Row(id='label1')),
 (Row(id='label6'), Row(id='label6'))
 (Row(id='label6'), Row(id='label2'))
 (Row(id='label3'), Row(id='label3'))]
```

Should return

```
data = [
 (Row(id='label1'), Row(id='label6'))
 (Row(id='label6'), Row(id='label2'))]
```

Update 3  :

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

data = [(Row(id='label1'), Row(id='label1')),
        (Row(id='label1'), Row(id='label6')),
        (Row(id='label6'), Row(id='label1')),
        (Row(id='label6'), Row(id='label6')),
        (Row(id='label6'), Row(id='label2')),
        (Row(id='label3'), Row(id='label3'))]

df = sc.parallelize(data)

df.groupByKey()\
  .flatMap(lambda (x,y): fn(x,y))\
  .map(lambda r: tuple(sorted(r)))\
  .distinct()\
  .take(5)

[(Row(id='label2'), Row(id='label6')), 
(Row(id='label1'), Row(id='label6'))]
```

returns :

```
  File "<ipython-input-39-dffaf6bcbb80>", line 12
    df.groupByKey()  .flatMap(lambda (x,y): fn(x,y))  .map(lambda r: tuple(sorted(r)))  .distinct()  .take(5)
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Update 4 :

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

data = [(Row(id='label1'), Row(id='label1')),
        (Row(id='label1'), Row(id='label6')),
        (Row(id='label6'), Row(id='label1')),
        (Row(id='label6'), Row(id='label6')),
        (Row(id='label6'), Row(id='label2')),
        (Row(id='label3'), Row(id='label3'))]

df = sc.parallelize(data)

df.groupByKey().flatMap(lambda (x,y): fn(x,y)).map(lambda r: tuple(sorted(r))).distinct().take(5)
```

returns :

```
 File "<ipython-input-302-dd76d08c9530>", line 12
    df.groupByKey().flatMap(lambda (x,y): fn(x,y)).map(lambda r: tuple(sorted(r))).distinct().take(5)
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: @blue-sky, why are you dropping this record? (Row(id='label3'), Row(id='label3'), label3 does not appear anywhere?

Comment: @Rags I'm dropping the record because it's the same id in both tuple positions.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this works for you

This is your data

```
data = [(Row(id='label1'), Row(id='label1')),
        (Row(id='label1'), Row(id='label6')),
        (Row(id='label6'), Row(id='label1')),
        (Row(id='label6'), Row(id='label6')),
        (Row(id='label6'), Row(id='label2')),
        (Row(id='label3'), Row(id='label3'))]

df = sc.parallelize(data)
```

The below will give what you wanted:

```
def fn(k, rl):
    fil=[]
    for row in rl:
        if row != k:
            fil.append((k, row))
    return fil

df.groupByKey()\
  .flatMap(lambda (x,y): fn(x,y))\
  .map(lambda r: tuple(sorted(r)))\
  .distinct()\
  .take(5)

[(Row(id='label2'), Row(id='label6')), 
(Row(id='label1'), Row(id='label6'))]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks but this fails, please see question update. Does this work for you with Python3 ?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the function definition. Please check now. The same can be achieved in a sinple way  'df.filter(lambda x: x[0] != x[1]).map(sorted).map(tuple).distinct().take(5)' like user6910411 mentioned

Comment: what did you change ?  I tried your updated code but error occurs, please see update 4 in question. Yes it does appear 'df.filter(lambda x: x[0] != x[1]).map(sorted).map(tuple).distinct().take(5)' also works

Comment: the change is Adding the function definition